# How to manually update android browser with latest (nightly) webkit?

Tags: android, html, webkit, video-streaming

Is it possible to update WebKit behind the Android 1.5/1.6/etc (prior to 2.2) browser?
I know latest nightly WebKit builds has great HTML5 support.
So, my intention is to provide html5 video streaming (and other features) support on all those droids.
Previously I was able to update WebKit engine on different devices with older Safari to meet my requirements (on any mac os x distros it's easy as updating WebKit.framework).

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to update WebKit behind
>   the Android 1.5/1.6/etc (prior to 2.2)
>   browser?

Not without rebuilding the firmware, and even then, you will probably have extensive work to do.

Comment: Ok, thanx.  
So, what is a minimum requirements (in terms of Android versions) for working html5 video support?  
Or, maybe, there is other way to stream rtsp/h.264aac/mp4 video on all those droids? Maybe I can autoopen links (videos) in built-in media player?

Comment: @headwire: I think HTML5 video arrived in Android 2.0. Whether it works for `WebView` versus the full Browser application, though, I do not know. "Or, maybe, there is other way to stream rtsp/h.264aac/mp4 video on all those droids?" -- sure, use `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView`, or perhaps a `VideoView`.